# Visual Studio 2015 SCSS Intellisense Not Functioning

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sass, intellisense, web-essentials

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  I have Web Essentials installed with the extensions for SASS/SCSS, however the menu doesn't appear as I had expected based on tutorials I'd found and, more importantly, the intellisense isn't working properly.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I can't find anyone who's running into this.
The thing is also that in Tools>Options>Text Editor it has SCSS as a category, but there's nothing within it that would indicate why it doesn't like it.

intellisense is not working

[image]

[Next to nothing in the Web Essentials Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYECx.png)

[image]

Comment: Which tutorial did you mentioned? From your screenshot, you need to make sure you already define the $blue-dark before you invoke it, you can check this SCSS syntax from Sass basic: http://sass-lang.com/guide. Define $blue-dark on the top, then use it later and the intellisense works fine on my side like here: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgl4sXYe6j80Oed7S

Comment: Eh, all the definitions are at the top of the file and I could only attach 2 screen shots, should have moved that definition down for demonstration purposes though.  The intellisense doesn't recognize it, but it compiles correctly.  But if you notice, the "a" tag and the "&" operators are also not being recognized.  And actually, now that I just reopened the project again this morning, now it doesn't compile...  yup.

Comment: The tutorial was: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Mij3b6dfMg,

Answer (score 2):

Alright, the solution I came to was derived from the fact that when I initially created the SCSS file, I had created it as a CSS file and then modified the extension.  I deleted it, specifically created an SCSS file using the template finder, pasted in my previous SCSS content, and everything works fine now.

Comment: Hi gabrielthursday, glad to hear that your issue solved and you can mark your reply as answer, that will helpful for other community members who meet the same or similar issue to check this useful information.